# Is synchronized function equivalent to synchronized([Class].this)]

Tags: java, synchronized

Have a look at the example below where `synchronized` is used twice:

```java
public class Demo {
  private Double mass = null;

  public synchronized void setMass(double mass) {
    this.mass = mass;
  }

  public Consumer<Double> createUpdater() {
    return new Consumer<>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(Double flow) {
        synchronized (Demo.this) {
          mass = mass + flow * 0.1;
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Will one block the simultaneous execution of the other block?
In other words, does the synchronized keyword on a function refer to instance ([Class].this) in Java?

Comment: Yes it is, in this context.  Yes, it will.

Comment: It is equivalent to `synchronized (this)` at all times if the method isn't `static`. I don't understand what exactly you mean by `[Class].this`, unless you are referring to the syntax for getting the enclosing instance of an inner class object, in which case the answer is 'no'.

Comment: Wow.  What createUpdater() returns is a closure on the Demo instance, yes?

Comment: @CryptoFool the demo code is imcomplete. we have different "updaters": some for flow addition and some for flow subtraction... they all contribute to updating the mass. the design is preliminary.

Comment: You could also use a lambda expression, which uses `this` the same way as the surrounding code, `public Consumer<Double> createUpdater() { return flow -> { synchronized(this) { mass += flow * 0.1; } }; }` This will, of course, fail when `mass` still has its initial value of `null`. You should really rethink this strategy. Boxing every value into a `Double`, just for the sake of an initial value (as all other updates never produce `null`), is questionable.